# Export list/array to CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export

done some googling but answers I have found seem to be more complex than what I need. I have a simple script to fetch DNS cache entries, and I'd like to export the results to a CSV in the most "powershell" manner. Code looks like this:

```
function Get-Dns
{
    $domains = @()
    $cmdOutput = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {ipconfig /displaydns}
    ForEach ($line in $($cmdOutput -split "`r`n"))
    {
        if ($line -like '*Record Name*'){
            $domain = $line -split ":"
            $domains += $domain[1]
    }
}
```

so I have an array, $domains, which I would like to use Export-CSV to essentially output a one column CSV with one domain per line. Using Export-CSV seems to just output the length of each element rather than the contents itself. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ipconfig /displaydns" is going to give you back a big'ol string array, which is going to be harder to work with. Try the native commandlets for DNS manipulation:

```
Get-DnsClientCache | Export-Csv -Path .\stuff.csv
```

If you're using Windows 7 or earlier, try this...

```
$dns_client_cache = @()
$raw_dns_data = ipconfig /displaydns
for ($element = 3; $element -le $raw_dns_data.length - 3; $element++) {
    if ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('Record Name') -gt 0 ) {
        if ( $dns_entry ) { $dns_client_cache += $dns_entry }
        $dns_entry = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'RecordName' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    } elseif ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('Record Type') -gt 0 ) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'RecordType' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    } elseif ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('Time To Live') -gt 0 ) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'TimeToLive' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    } elseif ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('Data Length') -gt 0 ) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'DataLength' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    } elseif ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('Section') -gt 0 ) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Section' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    } elseif ( $raw_dns_data[$element].IndexOf('CNAME Record') -gt 0 ) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $dns_entry -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CNAMERecord' -Value $raw_dns_data[$element].Split(':')[1].Trim()
    }
}

$dns_client_cache | Export-Csv -Path .\dns_stuff.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Sorry! I know it's messy.

Comment: Wow. Very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Quick question - this appears to be supported on some hosts I am testing on, but not on others? Is there a way to ensure it will run on any system with powershell installed? thanks!

Comment: Add the -CimSession parameter: -CimSession <remotemachine>

Comment: Ah, looks like Get-DnsClientCache is not supported on Win7. Lame! I think i will have to go down the cmd displaydns route then.

Comment: Yikes. Yea, Windows 7 doesn't have the needed OS bits for that commandlet. I believe you are correct.

Comment: No worries - good to know nonetheless. Appreciate all the assistance! Got it working with /displaydns

Answer (score 2):

The *most* PowerShell way:

```
(ipconfig /displaydns|where{$_-match'Record Name'})|%{$_.split(":")[1].Trim()}>dnscache.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same result but with using the Export-Csv function? I am trying to stay consistent with other aspects of the script that already exist.

Comment: Without seeing the other parts of your script I couldn't tell you how to do that. For data to properly output into a csv you need to create an object, I'll work out an example and post another answer.

Comment: actually, looks like @LordAdam has a good solution that will do what you are probably looking for, that's pretty much what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with to export multiple value array to csv

```
$Data | %{$_} | export-csv -nti -Path C:\
```